# Execute same logic for multiple multidimensional arrays

Tags: php, arrays, function, multidimensional-array, foreach

I'm currently trying the following:

I have multiple arrays defined. They all are filled by fetching data from the database, so they all contain the same columns/data structure, but with different data. For example, lets say the arrays are different schools, so there is:

```
//pseudoCode:
array1 = ({"Name: Peter", "Surname: not peter"},{"Name: doe", "Surname: john"});
array2 = ({"Name: asfwe", "Surname: qwfqwf"},{"Name: asfas", "Surname: fsbng"});
array3 = ({"Name: weqw", "Surname: wqeqewqw"},{"Name: doqweqwee", "Surname: wewe"});
```

Now, for all these arrays, I want to do the same things. In my case, I have multiple if else cases, checking the length of the array and doing some stuff.

So far I'm only doing it for array 1 though. Now my first idea was to simply copy  the logic and refactor all variable names to array2 respectively to array3, but this wouldn't make sense, because in my real case, its 10 arrays instead of 3 and the logic is about 150 lines of code, so I would have a lot of duplicate code and would need to change it everywhere, if something in the logic changes.

Now the question is: How can I do the same procedure for every array?

So what I would need is something like:

```
//pseudoCode again
foreach(array in array1, array2, array3, array4, array5,....){
//do something with variable "array", which is actually one of the defined arrays
}
```

A hint in the right direction would be great.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Using [`array_merge()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) ?

Comment: export all your logic to function that encapsulate your array modification?

Comment: @AymDev I still need to be able to differ between the arrays... Also I don't know the lengths of each array, only the structure

Comment: Then like @dWinder said, use a function.

Comment: @dWinder but how do I access my arrays in the function then? Of course, I give it to the function as parameter, but I mean how do I give all arrays to the function?

Comment: Ofcourse, I could use function doSomething($myArray){//do something with $myArray} and then call doSomething($array1); doSomething($array2); and so on, but could I also do this for all arrays at once in a loop instead of calling the function for each array?

Comment: `foreach ($all_your_arrays as $arr) { do_stuff_to_process_array($arr); }`? Basically, just add `[]` around your `array1, array2...arrayN` in your pseudocode to group them all in an array to create `$all_your_arrays`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Procedure code demand exporting logic to function:

```
function foo($array) {
    // modify the array or do what ever you need
    return $array; // in case it has been modify
}
```

Now can you function as:

```
foreach($arrays as &$arr)
    $arr = foo($arr); // calling the function on each array
    // the re-assign is just in case it has been modify
```

In this example `$arrays` stand for array with all your inner arrays as:

```
$arrays = array($array1, $array2, $array3, ...)
```

if your array as getting dynamicly from some other function / SQL code do:

```
$arrays = []; // init empty array
while (@SOME_CONDITION@) {
    $arrays[] = getAnotherArrayFunction(); // append the array to your array
}
```

Comment: oh man, I'm stupid, if this works, then it's really simpler then I thought.. The question is, how many dimensions can PHP handle? Would be be a problem, to access one item from $array1 (lets say the surname of peter) by then calling $arrays[0][0]["Surname"]? This would work right?

Comment: Yes. PHP can handle multi-dimension array with a lot of deeper level. and yes - you can access them as `$arrays[0][0]["Surname"]`

Comment: alright, thank you very much! :) Basically I was just missing the part to assign all arrays to one big array, so I didn't know how to work with the function for every array...